# How to access a tomcat server url without giving port number in vps server

Tags: tomcat, server, port, vps

I have a vps server on which i have installed tomcat server. I have some jsp web applications which are installed on tomcat server. Now every web application i have to access using the port number 8080. For eg: http://example.com:8080/webapp How can i get rid of that port number from the url and directly access the web application using url like this http://example.com/webapp How can i do it

Comment: open port 80 and configure connector with 80

Comment: If Tomcat is not running with root (and I don't recommend running with root), you can't listen on port 80. You just need to configure a port forwarding (depending on your Linux version : iptables, firewall-cmd).